# Why do files deleted with the command prompt not end up in the recycle bin?

Tags: windows, command-line, data-recovery, recycle-bin

Also, is it possible to recover files deleted with the cmd prompt?

Comment: How did you delete them?

Comment: I deleted them with del/s/q... What possibilities are you considering?

Comment: None; but I don't want to *assume* anything.

Answer (score 7):

When you delete from the Command Prompt you're working with the NTFS file system. There, delete means delete -- with no "undo" feature.
The **Recycle Bin** is a feature of the Windows Shell, not the filesystem. It's really a special folder where "deleted" files are moved until truly deleted by "Emptying" the **Recycle Bin**.

Were the files in a location protected by **File History**? If so, you shold be able to recover them.

Deleted file system files are sometimes recoverable by 3rd-party software, but if you've continued to use the computer, the chances grow slimmer.

Comment: I would almost give it a +1. The last paragraph prevents me from giving a +1. Sure, you can recover deleted files if you know exactly how and have the right tools, but in most cases, it seems really hard to do for a beginner. I would therefor word it as: no you cannot. Maybe with undelete software, but a successful recovery grows slimmer the longer you wait, and is not as easy as one would seem.

Comment: I added that for completeness. Had I said "no you cannot", some contratrian surely would have chimed in. I also though it likely the OP may have elsewhere seen promises of recovery --- thought it might avoid a follow-up question. :D